# Write-only queue?

Tags: c#, .net, security

I'm working on an application that loads untrusted assemblies via an interface. Each of those assemblies should be able to add one or more GameAction objects to a thread-safe queue used by the server.

The first iteration of design was to just pass the queue--something like this:

```
public interface IGameClient
{
  void HandleStateChange(IGameState gameState, 
                         ref Queue<IGameAction> actionQueue);
}
```

But, the problem with this is that it gives an untrusted assembly access to a shared queue, allowing it to manipulate other members of the queue and discover information about other queue actions.

The second pass was:

```
public interface IGameClient
{
  void HandleStateChange(IGameState gameState);
  GameActionDelegate event HasNewEvent; // passes IGameAction as a parameter
}
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't necessarily allow for the ordering or grouping of actions.

What I'm really hoping for is to be able to pass a reference to an object that encapsulates the thread-safe queue, but only exposes Enqueue(). But, I'm afraid that an untrusted assembly could manipulate a private Queue object using reflection.

So, what's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thoughts in no particular order:

1) Events *do* guarantee ordering (or at least, your implementation could guarantee whatever ordering you want, and the simplest implementations will preserve ordering).

2) I don't see why you'd want to pass the queue by reference in the first example of the interface. It may be worth checking that you understand [parameter passing and "ref"](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/threads/parameters.html).

3) If you come up with an interface which only exposes Enqueue then the implementation presumably won't *be* a `Queue<T>`. It might *contain* a `Queue<T>`, but if you really don't trust assemblies not to mess around with your private members, you should load them in such a way that you don't grant them the relevant reflection permissions.

Another alternative might be to pass in an `Action<IGameAction>` which the client can call when it wants to add an item to the queue. The delegate would be created from whatever Enqueue method you've got.

Comment: The "ref" isn't because it's necessary. It's meant to be a cue to the third-party developer that "this is meant to be manipulated" (and it was a first sketch.)

Comment: Please don't use ref like that - it's not what it's there for, and would have allowed the method to replace your queue with their own one!

Answer (score 2):

Don't expose the queue at all--simply expose a method on a facade that allows the GameClient to submit an entry that the GameServer will place on the internal queue.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the HandleStateChange method return an IEnumerable<IGameAction>, IList<IGameAction> or IGameAction[]:

```
public interface IGameClient
{
  IGameAction[] HandleStateChange(IGameState gameState);
}
```

Then use that return value to add actions to the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a newly-created instance of queue, and when the HandleStateChange returns, merge the stuff from your dummy queue into the real queue.